# JavaScript to get user input from editable table cell and send to server via json

Tags: ajax

I created a table with five columns dynamically. Two (the second and third column) of the five columns should be editable on the fly. Each time when user click on one the editable table cell, JavaScript should catch the user input and send the data to the server in json format. I have problem catch the user input and send to the server. Please help. This is my sample code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Editable table</title> 
    <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">        
        @import "css/table.css"; 
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>   

</head>
<body id="dt_example">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="full_width big">
                Data table<br />                
        </div>

    <div class="editab">
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Contract Number</th>
                    <th>Current Status</th>                     
                    <th>Sale Balance Amount</th>
                    <th>Interest Rate</th>
                    <th>Discount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>                
                    <td>00123</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">A30</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">$1,500.00</td>
                    <td>3.99 %</td>
                    <td>140</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                
                    <td>00234</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">B20</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">$2,500.00</td>
                    <td>3.99 %</td>
                    <td>160</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                
                    <td>00345</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">C40</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">$3,500.00</td>
                    <td>3.99 %</td>
                    <td>180</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                
                    <td>00456</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">A20</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">$4,500.00</td>
                    <td>3.99 %</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                
                    <td>00567</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">B30</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">$5,500.00</td>
                    <td>3.99 %</td>
                    <td>225</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                
                    <td>00678</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">C10</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">$6,500.00</td>
                    <td>3.99 %</td>
                    <td>250</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                
                    <td>00789</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">A30</td>
                    <td onClick="editTableCell(this)">$7,500.00</td>
                    <td>3.99 %</td>
                    <td>300</td>
                </tr>                   
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var SelectState = false;
    var SelectedElement = null;
    var TextInput = null;
    var CellText = null;
    var txt     = "test";
    var idcount  = 0;

    function editTableCell( e ){

      if ( SelectState == false ){

        SelectedElement = e;
        CellText = e.innerHTML;     
        e.innerHTML = "";

        var objInput = document.createElement("input");
        objInput.type = 'text';
        objInput.value = CellText;
        objInput.id = "txt" + idcount++;
        objInput.onkeypress = editTextBox;
        objInput.size = 15;

        TextInput = objInput;
        e.appendChild(objInput);

        SelectState = true;

      } else if (e != SelectedElement) {
        SelectedElement.innerHTML = CellText;
        SelectState = false;
      }
    }

    function editTextBox( e ){

      if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        e = window.event;
        key = e.keyCode;
      }

      else if (navigator.appName == "Netscape"){
        key = e.which;
      }

      if ( key == 13 ){
        SelectedElement.innerHTML = TextInput.value;
        SelectState = false;
      }

      else if ( key == 27 ){
        SelectedElement.innerHTML = CellText;
        SelectState = false;
      }
    }   

/*      var attrName  = "":
    var attrValue = "";
    if ($('#test1')
    {
        attrName=  "editField01";
        attrValue = $(#test1).val();
    }
    if ($('#test2')
    {
        attrName=  "editField02";
        attrValue = $(#test2).val();
    }

    if ($('#test3')
    {
        attrName=  "editField03";
        attrValue = $(#test3).val();
    }

     var values = '{"' + attrName + '":' + attrValue + '}';
      $.ajax({
        url: serverUrl + "/abc/contract/" + poolId,
        async: false,
        type: "PUT",
        data: JSON.stringify(values),
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: showResponse(json) {
          // TODO: What info is returned in the data structure?
          showResponse;
        },
        error: function(err) {
          alert("Failed to update the attribute");
          htmlErrorDialog(err.responseText);
        }
      });*/

    function showResponse(json)  { 
      if(json.success){
        // handle successful response here
        alert("user input from column sent successfully!");
      } else {
        // handle unsuccessful response here
        alert("user input fail to send. Please try again");
      }
    } 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually passing the json data to `showResponse`:

```
    success: showResponse(json) {
      // TODO: What info is returned in the data structure?
      showResponse;
    },
```

Pass it along as so, and make sure that json is an actual object and that you don't need to parse it first:

```
    success: function(json) {
      // check that json is an actual object via an alert
      // alert(json);
      showResponse(json);
    },
```

EDIT: Okay after a lot of working around, I have a simple test case for making the fields editable. Please note it uses jquery, and comments are inline:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Date: 2011-05-10 -->
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Contract Number</th>
                <th>Current Status</th>                     
                <th>Sale Balance Amount</th>
                <th>Interest Rate</th>
                <th>Discount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>         
                <!-- The "identifier" class makes it so we have an id
                    to pass to our ajax script so we know what to change -->       
                <td class="identifier">00123</td>
                <td class="editable">A30</td>
                <td class="editable">$1,500.00</td>
                <td>3.99 %</td>
                <td>140</td>
            </tr>                   
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>     
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // bind our event handler to all td elements with class editable
        $('td.editable').bind('click', function() {
            // Only create an editable input if one doesn't exist
            if(!$(this).has('input').length) {
                // Get the text from the cell containing the value
                var value = $(this).html();
                // Create a new input element with the value of the cell text
                var input = $('<input/>', {
                    'type':'text',
                    'value':value,
                    // Give it an onchange handler so when the data is changed
                    // It will do the ajax call
                    change: function() {
                        var new_value = $(this).val();
                        // This finds the sibling td element with class identifier so we have
                        // an id to pass to the ajax call
                        var cell = $(this).parent();
                        // Get the position of the td cell...
                        var cell_index = $(this).parent().parent().children().index(cell);
                        // .. to find its corresponding header
                        var identifier = $('thead th:eq('+cell_index+')').html();
                        //ajax post with id and new value
                        $(this).replaceWith(new_value);
                    }
                });
                // Empty out the cell contents...
                $(this).empty();
                // ... and replace it with the input field that has the value populated
                $(this).append(input);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you onteria. Somehow whenever I uncomment the code from "var attrName = "";" on, my code to make table cell editable would not run. Also, I still cannot figure out on how to pass user input from the any of the editable table to the server, after user finish enter data.

Comment: @C.L. I've updated my response with a small test case using a row and jquery to make the rows editable. Please check the code over and see if it helps you understand where the AJAX call works in.

Comment: Thank you onteria. Your code works great. If I need to send the user entered data from the editable table cell to the server in json format, having column title as key and user input as value, so the data can be send in { "Sale Balance Amount": "$2000" } format to the server to be updated, how to change the ajax call to accommodate that?

Comment: @C.L. Updated the code for that. Please see `var identifier`'s new value, which uses the corresponding header cell instead.

Comment: onteria,thanks a million for helping me out with the really effective code and the comments which explain what each statement is for. The AJAX code update the user entered input table cell. While the same data will get past to the server to update the database. Right?